# React create nav from components displayed

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [available on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nuc5rk?file=index.tsx).

Its a simple app with 4 components in the index page

I'd like to create a nav for the components added.

I dont want every component in the nav.

I'm trying to do it with useState and add the components I want in the nav with

```
setNav([...nav, 'About'])
```

I'm getting the error

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'
```

What causing this error

Is it possible to create a nav like this

Comment: You cannot call `setNav` as part of the render of your component. `setNav` should be triggered from an event or `useEffect`.

Comment: Here is a quick example with a toggle button for products: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tcucpv?file=index.tsx